# Cakephp3 how to bulk Save or Update records

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Using Cake-PHP3 I am trying to bulk save or update (i.e if record is existing update, otherwise insert)

Say I have an array

```
$records=
[
['id'=1,'data'='data'],
['id'=2,'data'='data'],
['id'=3,'data'='data']
];
```

How can i bulk save or update it?

I tried using saveMany but it always results in duplicate key error if the record exist.

```
$entities = $this->MyModel->newEntities($records);
$this->saveMany ($entities);
```

I know that there is a solution using the epilog with mysql "on duplicate update"

```
foreach ($records AS $record) {
  $query = $this->Articles->query();
  $query
    ->insert($record_fields)
    ->values($record)
    ->epilog('ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field=field+1')
    ->execute();
}
```

But that solution seems to save each record on its own and not in a bulk way which is very important to me (tons of records)

Comment: Please show us your `saveMany` code, including where you are patching the entities. And look at your `accessible` list to see if you are even allowed to set the `id` field.

Comment: Post you save code here, so we can help you further

Answer (score 0):

Cake\ORM\Table::saveMany($entities, $options = [])

Using this you can save multiple entities in cakephp3.

```
$data = [];  // Your data
$entities = $this->MyTable->newEntities($data);
$result   = $this->MyTable->saveMany($entities);
```

Comment: Thanks @boni, however the question is how to save while duplicate entries may exist in the table. (i.e data records exist in DB)

Comment: Cake\ORM\Table::beforeSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options)
The Model.beforeSave event is fired before each entity is saved. Here you can check duplicate entries exist or not then depend on it ,update or create entry in DB

Comment: But this is the same as before inserting a row checking if it exists or not which negates the point of bulk upsert, and will result in poor performance.